# NullPointerException on Null Check

Tags: java

I am messed up with the below Code Cannot able to distinguish between the two code Snippets:

```
String Check=null;

if(Check!=null && Check.isEmpty()){
  System.out.println("Get Inside");
}
```

Above Code works Fine and Print the Message.

```
if(Check==null && Check.isEmpty()){
  System.out.println("get Inside")
}
```

this code will throw the NullPointerException.Not able to distinguish between this Code Please Help.

Comment: Remember this:
== != !=

Comment: @dirkk Actually the `==` is fine (In the sense that it doesn't throw an exception). This check doesn't throw a NPE. The problem is that the other side is evaluated, then the NPE is thrown.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Sure, with "this" I refered to the whole statement. I just think it is very obvious as you first check that `Check` is null and then nonetheless access this element.

Answer (score 7):

The `&&` operator is a *short-circuit*, it doesn't evaluate the right hand side if it's not necessary. In this case, it's necessary:

```
if(Check==null && Check.isEmpty()){
  System.out.println("get Inside")
}
```

If `Check` is `null` (and that's the case), you'll continue to check the condition after the `&&`, and you get `Check.isEmpty()`. Since `Check` is `null`, it's like `null.isEmpty()` which is a NEP.

Why?

When two expressions have `&&` between them, if the first one is false, the answer will always be false and the other side won't be checked, but when the first is `true`, you have to continue and check the other side to know if all the expression should be evaluated to `true` or `false`.

But when you have:

```
if(Check!=null && Check.isEmpty()){
     System.out.println("get Inside")
}
```

Then the right side won't be reached, since it's redundant to check it. You already got `false`, and it doesn't matter if you get `true` or `false` on the right side, the result will be `false` since this is an `AND` (*FALSE && WHATEVER = FALSE*). So why checking?

[This link](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs132/Weekly/W02/SCBooleans.html) might help you.

*(I recommend you to follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) and make the variables begin with a lowercase).*

Comment: Thanks sir! I like your answer as  I was confused with that snippets.Now I got the Idea why it was throwing the Error.

Comment: Your're welcome my friend, I'm glad it helped you, and of course you can accept it if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

`&&` means evaluating the left side first, if `false` then the whole expression is `false`. If the left side is `true`, it evaluates the right side. In your case:

```
if(Check==null && Check.isEmpty())
```

if `Check` is `null`, next it evaluates `Check.isEmpty()` which throws `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Check==null && Check.isEmpty())
```

if Check really equals null the in the other condition you're just saying `null.isEmpty` which ofcourse will lead to `NullPointerException` since `&&` is irrelevant and pointless you needed `||` instead

```
if(Check==null || Check.isEmpty()){
  //no NullPointerException
  System.out.println("get Inside")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First let me tell you the difference between `logical OR(||) and logical AND(&&)`.
When you use `logical OR`, if the first expression is `TRUE`, `the second expression is not evaluated`; that means if any one expression is TRUE, the condition is satisfied and the flow passes into the loop. But in case of `AND, all the expressions must satisfy to TRUE to satisfy the condition`. And if any one of the expression evaluates to be FALSE, the condition is not satisfied.

Also keep in mind, we get a `NPE(Null Pointer Exception) when we try to call methods upon variables whose value = null`.

So in the First Case:

Check != null : the first condition is false, no further processing as logical AND returns FALSE if one of the expression is FALSE. Second expression is not evaluated (Check.isEmpty or whatsoever). No NPE as we are not calling methods upon any null value.

Second Case:

First Condition is satisfied, so second condition is evaluated which throws NPE as Check = null and we are call method upon a null value.

Hope you get it!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Check==null && Check.isEmpty()){
  System.out.println("get Inside")
}
```

In above Check is null so it goes and look up for next condition which is isEmpty that throws NullPointerException.